# Noise from a relay during switching

Tags: power, relay, isolated

Is okay to have a load use the same ground as the coil supply of the relay. From my understanding relays do sometimes 'bounce' when switching from N/C to N/O. This inturn can then create some form of noise within your circuit.

If the output of relay is then connected to the same ground as the coil then wouldn't this 'isolated' circuit also be affected by this noise? If so then is not good practice to use isolated or tow power supplies at the coil part of the relay and the COM,N/C. N/O pins of the relay?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqpCjt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a general question, so the answer, as always, is that it depends.

When disconnected, the coil will indeed try to the same current through it and will create spikes as the field in it collapses; that is the reason for D2.  But in case of a "bounce" you will get some transients on your supply line and possibly your ground line.

But whether this has any negative consequences, will highly depend on your circuit and PCB.  If the relay is PCB mounted with a solid copper ground plane, you are probably not going to notice any issues.  It also depends on what sensitivity the rest of your circuit has in the supply line.  If you are feeding the supply straight into sensitive circuitry, you'll see it.  But if you go through a regulator with a high PSRR, it will probably be fine.

For whatever it's worth, I almost always use the same ground for relays.  I have used that topology in unmanned vehicles, small robots, control/monitoring systems and never had any issues.  Only time I had an issue is when I forgot to install D2, but that's a whole other story.